# HTML parse with python and bs

Tags: python, html-parsing

I need to get a list of all Android devices and in order to do this without copy/pasting each item from Android.com I thought a Python script would do the job easier. The problem is I only started learning python three days ago.

Now, this is the HTML structure that I want to parse and extract only the string of the `<a>` attribute of each `<li>`.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
        <div class="main">
            <div class="listing">
                <form id="listing" class="">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <p>
                                <a class="title" href="/devices/detail/xperia-p">Xperia™ P</a>
                            </p>
                        </li>
```

This is the python script I used:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, Jun 16 2011, 16:59:05) 
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
session = requests.session()
req = session.get('http://www.android.com/devices/?country=all&f=phone')
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content)
print soup.findAll("a", "title")
```

Obviously in this setup I get all the `<a>` tag, not just the string. I know that I can use the `text` argument but I don't know how to used with the CSS selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for a in soup.findAll("a", "title"):
    print a.get_text()
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

Answer (score -3):

Try with an XML parser such as  [xml.dom.minidom](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.minidom.html).

I don't remember the syntax, but it's pretty easy to use.